# JQuery - Make .slideToggle specific to each list

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a `.slideToggle` making a list dropdown, but unfortunately it makes all lists dropdown, I need to make it only dropdown the list below the `a` that I'm clicking on. Sure this is a simple issue, still pretty new to jquery.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/darcyvoutt/shErA/

Comment: Please add the relevant code into your question (HTML, JavaScript and CSS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following finds the next `ul` element and runs `slideToggle()` on it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav-filters-list-item a').click(function () {
        $(this).next('ul').slideToggle(70);
    });
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shErA/2/)

Comment: You're welcome - I just (slightly) improved my answer and added an update jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an id for each dropdown like this:

```
<ul class="nav-filters-list">
    <li class="nav-filters-list-item" id="genre"><a href="#">Genre</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Home</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-filters-list-item" id="tags"><a href="#">Tags</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Home</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-filters-list-item"><a href="#">Date</a>

    </li>
    <li class="nav-filters-list-item"><a href="#">Order</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#genre a').click(function () {
        $('#genre ul').slideToggle(70);
    });
    $('#tags a').click(function () {
        $('#tags ul').slideToggle(70);
    });
});
```